# Facing a difficulty in a bubble sort algorithm in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

First of all I am beginner in C, so I am sorry if my question seems stupid. 
I was learning how to use the bubble sort algorithm in C, and I came through this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[10] = {
        78,
        16,
        21,
        7,
        13,
        9,
        22,
        52,
        67,
        19
    };

    //Listing the array before sorting

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }

    //Sorting the arrays

    for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Listing the array after sorting

    printf("\n\nThis is the sorted array\n");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine, but what I want to understand is how in the second for loop it is written `inner = outer`, and in the next if statement it is comparing the elements of the array were one of them has the same number as inner and the other has the same number as outer. 
And since we said that `inner = outer`, that means that we are comparing the same element.
The way I think about it is, if `outer = 0`, and since `inner = outer`, then `inner` will be `0` too, so the next if statement will be `if (nums[0] < nums[0])` and that doesn't make any sense.

I know that I am probably wrong about it because the code works fine, but what did I think wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should get into the habit of properly indenting and aligning your code, immediately.  Improperly indented code is difficult to read, even for the one who wrote it.

Comment: Yes it should be `for (inner = outer + 1; ...` it seems. Although this not break the code just make it less optimal by having one plus essentially pointless iteration.

Comment: When `inner == outer`, then the loop body does nothing, so it is perfectly ok.

Comment: Not the answer but you may use the standard `i` and `j` instead of `outer` and `inner`

Comment: What does this do for `int nums[10] = { 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2 } ;` ?

Comment: Well I didn't write this code, I am reading "C for absolute beginners" book and this was a code example on bubble sorting. I didn't exactly copy the code from the book, I did remove from it the unwanted parts and comments.

Comment: @Ctx But if the loop body does nothing how is the array sorted. Sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: @notopython The loop body does nothing for `inner == outer`, so it does nothing wrong, too. This is what I meant. Otherwise, it _might_ do something. But as ChrisHall insinuates, the `didSwap` logic is utterly broken, so it will _not_ sort the example array. It is conceptionally not even a bubblesort at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of your Bubble Sort is that on each scan the "bubble" is the largest value seen so far, so at the end of the scan, the largest value has "bubbled" to the top.  Then you repeat from the beginning, but each time around (clearly) you have one less value you need to consider.  Also, if at the end of a scan, nothing moved, then everything is in order and you can stop.

So the Bubble Sort might look like this:

```
    for (int n = 10 ; n > 0 ; n--)
      {
        bool no_swaps ;

        no_swaps = true ;
        for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; ++i)
          {
            if (nums[i-1] > nums[i])
              {
                int temp ;
                temp = nums[i-1];
                nums[i-1] = nums[i];
                nums[i]   = temp;
                no_swaps = false ;
              } ;
          } ;

        if (no_swaps)
          break ;
      } ;
```

Or:

```
    for (int n = 10 ; n > 0 ; n--)
      {
        bool no_swaps ;
        int bubb ;

        no_swaps = true ;
        bubb = nums[0] ;
        for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; ++i)
          {
            int this ;

            this = nums[i] ;
            if (bubb <= this)
              bubb = this ;
            else
              {
                nums[i-1] = this ;
                nums[i]   = bubb ;
                no_swaps = false;
              } ;
          } ;

        if (no_swaps)
          break ;
      } ;
```

which, perhaps, makes it clearer that the eponymous "bubble" (`bubb`) is the largest value found in the current scan (or the rightmost largest, if have seen 2 or more with that value).

If you remove the `didSwap` from your sort, it will work fine.  Like Bubble Sort, each pass of your sort moves one item to its final destination.  Your sort always does `(n-1)*(n-2)/2` comparisons, which is the same as the worst case for Bubble Sort.  But the Bubble Sort best case is `(n-1)` -- if the values are already in order !

So a real Bubble Sort has an edge over your sort.  Nevertheless, Bubble Sort is also generally **O(n^2)** and, therefore, about as useful as a chocolate teapot except when **n** is small.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Much appreciated !!

Comment: Yeah, there are many better spring algorithms. Bubble sort is generally taught in C classes/courses though as it's easy to understand and implement. I'd never use it under any other sort of circumstances though.

Comment: For Quick Sort (or any other divide-and-conquer) there comes a point where splitting and recursing costs more in overhead than it saves in comparisons etc.  Bubble Sort and Shaker Sort are simple and have attractive best cases, so you might use them at the leaves of a divide-and-conquer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not stupid question. You successfully spotted an inefficiency. The inner loop first iteration is indeed pointless, but it won't cause any trouble. The right way would be to start it from `outer + 1` instead of `outer`.

Comment: So what changes in the second iteration that makes it different from the first iteration?

Comment: That in the second iteration `inner` value is `outer + 1` so `inner != outer` therefore in the `if` there is actually meaningfull comparisons like `nums[0] < nums[1]` for example. Which make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the initialisation of `inner` in the *inner* loop could be changed to `inner = outer + 1` as the test will always be false in the first iteration.

Note however that if the first element is also the smallest, all tests in this *inner* loop will be false and `didSwap` will not be set to `1`, causing the *outer* loop to stop too. This is incorrect if the rest of the array is not sorted.

You can fix this problem by changing the loop to:

```
for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
    for (inner = outer + 1; inner < 10; inner++) {
        if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
            temp = nums[inner];
            nums[inner] = nums[outer];
            nums[outer] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Which will perform 45 iterations in all cases.

To improve the best case performance, you must slightly change the algorithm to only swap adjacent items:

```
for (outer = 10; outer-- > 0; ) {
    didSwap = 0;
    for (inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++) {
        if (nums[inner] > nums[inner + 1]) {
            temp = nums[inner];
            nums[inner] = nums[inner + 1];
            nums[inner + 1] = temp;
            didSwap = 1;
        }
    }
    if (didSwap == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will run in linear time if the array is already sorted, but still take **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** iterations on average.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

What if your array already has the biggest(or the smallest number) at first position.Your programme will stop when outer equals 0.(Because didSwap is 0).If you wanna use some variables like didSwap or lastSwapIndex,bubble sort should compare array[x] and array[x-1].Your algorithm looks like Selection sort more than Bubble sort.

Comment: Yes I agree with you about the didSwap. Although it should be used to decrease the number of iterations if possible, it could also mess the code and cause the array not to sort if its smallest value is in the top.